# Javascript trouble

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, calculator

I am trying to make a calculator with Javascript, and I'm having a few problems...
The code is at http://jsfiddle.net/NwkQW/10/.

1. Try adding some values, and you'll see that the box that says TOTAL will change according to the values you enter.  ***However***, you'll also see that if you click CLEAR FORM, the value will not go back to TOTAL.  How do I do that?
2. I want to link to the javascript (e.g. `<script type="text/javascript" src="mydomain.com/calculate.js></script>`), but if I try, it doesn't work right!  HELP!!!

Thanks!

Comment: `<input type="reset">` sets all `<input>` elements to their default value. The total box is not one of them, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a onClick to your clear form button like:

```
onClick="document.getElementById('totalDiv').innerHTML='';"
```

reset won't clear anything that's not a form element

see http://jsfiddle.net/NwkQW/16/

Comment: The problem with this is that the onClick will tend to execute *before* the form is reset.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mydomain.com/calculate.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add http://www. to the beginning of your source.  You are trying to go to http://www.mydomain.com/mydomain.com/calculate.js assuming this file lives at /

Comment: Sorry, that's what I do.  I just forgot when I was posting the question.  But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `totalDiv` to an input element and it will get cleared along with everything else.  Or, don't rely on form reset and just clear everything in a method.